# how to save the List inside the object using linq to xml?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to save a list of objects with nested lists in XDocument. So how to implement it?

I have a class:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public List<string> Authors { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And a class to store it all:

```
public class FileBookStore : IEntryStore<Book>
{
    private List<Book> loadedBooks;
    private string filename;
    ...


    private static async Task<IEnumerable<Book>> ReadDataAsync(string filename)
    {
        ...
        IEnumerable<Book> result = XDocument.Parse(text)
            .Root
            .Elements("book")
            .Select(e =>
                new Book
                {
                    Title = e.Attribute("title").Value,
                    Isbn = e.Attribute("isbn").Value,
                    Authors = new List<string>() //and here
                });
        return result;
    }

    static async Task SaveDataAsync(string filename, IEnumerable<Book> books)
    {
        XDocument root = new XDocument(
            new XElement("catalog", 
                books.Select(n =>
                    new XElement("book",
                        new XAttribute("title", n.Title ?? ""),
                        new XAttribute("isbn", n.Isbn ?? ""),
                        //stuck in a line below 
                        new XElement("authors", books.Select(n => new XElement("author"), new XAttribute("name"))),
                        new XAttribute("pages", n.Pages),
                        new XAttribute("year", n.Year),
                        new XAttribute("publisher", n.Publisher ?? "")))));

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(root.ToString()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

    }
```

I'm totally hung up on this part. How do I save and load objects to/from the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line you are stuck on to:

```
//stuck in a line below 
new XElement("authors", n.Authors.Select(x => new XElement("author", new XAttribute("name",x)))),
```